# Add class to dataTable cell, when the value is "none"

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to add a class to particular cell, when the cell contains the string "none".
Can anybody help me achieve this?

I am getting the response from REST GET call, and populating the table with required fields using `table.fnAddData(data);`

If the value of any field is "none", I need to highlight the cell with a style, which is defined in a class.

Comment: Can't you use Datatables ajax options? that could simplify the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector which will allow you to query the DOM based on text contained within the element.

Here's an example"

```js
$(function () {
  $('td:contains(none)').addClass('special')
})
```

```css
.special {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
       Something
     </td>
     <td>
       none
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```